# How to delete table rows that have not matches rows in second table

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I have 2 tables in 1 database.
In the 2 tables there are several rows with the same contents.

```
table visitor
--------------------------
id      |   mytoken1    |
--------------------------
1       |   token_abcd  |
2       |   token_efgh  |
3       |   token_ijkl  |
4       |   token_mnop  |
--------------------------

table favorites
--------------------------
id      |   mytoken2    |
--------------------------
1       |   token_abcd  |
2       |   token_efgh  |
3       |   token_ijkl  |
4       |   token_mnop  |
5       |   token_aaaa  |
6       |   token_bbbb  |
7       |   token_cccc  |
8       |   token_dddd  |
--------------------------
```

How do I delete the `mytoken2` column that is not in the `mytoken1` column?
So in the example above I want to delete 4 rows of data, including:

```
token_aaaa
token_bbbb
token_cccc
token_dddd
```

I have tried to find a solution until I was dizzy but it has not been resolved, I hope someone will help me here ..

Comment: It's often quicker to create a new table, retaining just the rows you want to keep, and then replacing the old table

Answer (score 0):

You can do using **NOT IN**

```
DELETE FROM favorites
WHERE token2 NOT IN (SELECT token1 FROM visitor)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`.

```
DELETE FROM favorites
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                     FROM visitor
                                     WHERE visitor.mytoken1 = favorites.mytoken2);
```

Comment: it uses a lot of connections, my server can't execute the script because there are thousands of data in the column

Answer (score 0):

JOIN also can be used here:

```
DELETE favorites.*
FROM favorites
LEFT JOIN visitor ON visitor.mytoken1 = favorites.mytoken2
WHERE visitor.id IS NULL;
```

Here you can [test SQL query](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=cba7c8c2e1c5934b64db711743e0e8e1&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)